# Redirect visitor to the specific page only at the first visit

Tags: php, wordpress

title says it all.

The visitors that comes to the index page of the Wordpress should be redirected to other page only the first time.

What is the easiest way to achieve this with cookies?

Comment: What have you tried? Should be something as simple as `if(cookie set){go to this page;} else {go to that page;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to the functions.php file of your theme:

```
function check_for_redirect() {
    $days_to_expire = 30;

    if (!is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['already_visited'])) {
        setcookie('already_visited', true, time() + 86400 * $days_to_expire);
        wp_redirect('http://www.example.com', 302); //change the URL and status to whatever you want
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'check_for_redirect');
```

Comment: That's perfect StathisG, how can I add that you redirect people only from specific page. 

Which means that I will redirect people to site B only if I'm on site A.

Comment: @JohnDoeTheOne Off the top of my head, you can use the [`get_site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url) function and add the check for the domain in the if statement, e.g. `if (!is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['already_visited']) && get_site_url() === 'your url')`.